# Validating an inequality

Tags: inequalities, resolve

I want to show that:

$$
\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+_0,\quad
1+a^{2017}+b^{2017} \geq a^{10}b^7+a^7b^{2000}+a^{2000}b^{10}
$$

I used `Simplify` and then `Resolve`. That is taking forever:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, 
   a >= 0 && b >= 0 &&
   1 + a^2017 + b^2017 >= a^7 b^7 (a^3 + a^1993 b^3 + b^1993)], 
   Reals]
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This is a hard inequality likely proved by a trick. In my opinion, Mathematica uses standard methods to this end. That takes a lot of time. Mathematica easily proves a such type inequality with lesser powers, e.g. `Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, a >= 0 && b >= 0, 
  1 + a^10 + b^10 - a^2 b^7 - a^7 b - a b^2 >= 0]]` and/or  `Minimize[{1 + a^10 + b^10 - a^2 b^7 - a^7 b - a b^2, 
  a >= 0 && b >= 0}, {a, b}]`. The former performs `True`  and the latter produces `{0, {a -> 1, b -> 1}}`.

Comment: The code and the formatted expression do not show the same inequality. Which makes it difficult to figure out what exactly is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
NMinimize[{ 1 + a^2017 + b^2017 - a^7 b^7 (a^3 + a^1993 b^3 + b^1993), 
            a >= 0 && b >= 0}, {a, b}]

(*
{0., {a -> 1., b -> 1.}}
*)
```

QED.

Answer (score 0):

to me, it seems to suffice to show equality for a=b=1, and further look at the behaviour for a and b close to 1:

```
it = a^10 b^7 + a^7 b^2000 + a^2000 b^10;
it /. {a^i_ -> 1 + i \[Alpha], b^j_ -> 1 + j \[Beta]} //Expand
```

giving

```
3 + 2017 \[Alpha] + 2017 \[Beta] + 34070 \[Alpha] \[Beta]
```

I notice that the last term makes the right side always bigger than the left if both a and b are >1 or both <1.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can try this one.

```
NMinimize[1 + a^2017 + b^2017 - a^10 b^7 - a^7 b^2000 - a^2000 b^10, {a, b}]
```

Comment: This is not it: in particular, you don't take into account the condition $ a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+_0$.